# How do I add startup applications in Lubuntu/Lxde?

Tags: boot, lubuntu, lxde

I want to add Gnome-Do to my startup applications in Lubuntu 10.04 and the only reference I've found on the net is to edit /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart. But surely there must be a way to do this on a user basis?

Comment: Just a note of warning that my lubuntu system had "Disable autostarted applications" set to "config-only", which (as the name suggests) disables applications in the .config/autostart. Make sure this is set to "no", if you'd like to launch startup applications. It can be found in the GUI through: Desktop -> Preferences -> Default applications for LXSession -> Autostart -> Disable autostarted applications -> no

Answer (score 26, accepted):

http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Autostart

> Add a .desktop file to your ~/.config/autostart directory (create one if not available) with 3 lines saying :
>
> ```
>  [Desktop Entry]
>  Type=Application
>  Exec=wicd-client -n
> ```

Comment: Interestingly the wiki is rot

Answer (score 9):

If the program you want to start has a `*.desktop` file, then simply copy or symlink it into the `~/.config/autostart` directory.

Source:

- http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXSession#autostart
- http://standards.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html

Otherwise, for commands in general,

> "For per-user autostart, use the `~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart` file."

It has the same format as `/etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart`

Source:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/47532/autostart-dropbox-in-lubuntu/47570#47570
- http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXSession#autostart

Answer (score 4):

Preferences > Desktop Session Settings

From here you can add or remove startup programs.

Comment: With the latest LXDE install, this program seems missing.  How can I invoke it with command line?

Answer (score 3):

In case you don't like editing *.desktop files manually or the app you need does not have a *.desktop file in `/usr/share/applications` you could simply open `~/.config/autostart` in `pcmanfm`, right-click on white space and select <kbd>Create New</kbd> -> <kbd>Shortcut</kbd> and fill in the `Command` field with whatever you need.

Answer (score 2):

This works for Lubuntu LXQt 20.04:

> **Preferences** -> **LXQt settings** -> **Session Settings** -> **Autostart**