# LXDE (Lubuntu) can't add an autostart app

Tags: python, lubuntu, lxde, autostart

There are several answers for this on the internet including this one: [How do I add startup applications in Lubuntu/Lxde?](https://superuser.com/questions/146457/how-do-i-add-startup-applications-in-lubuntu-lxde)

However, it simply does not work. 14.04 version of LUbuntu allows to both set the path to an autostart app in GUI as well as by creating a .desktop file in ~/.config/startup folder. I tried both ways, nothing. I'm trying .py python GUI scripts to execute on startup. Some of them do, some of them don't. It's pretty random, I tried from the desktop, home folder, completely random and doesn't work with 90% of scripts. Any ideas? Pulling out my hair by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I succeeded in getting autostart working by adding .desktop files to /etc/xdg/autostart. Files /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart and /etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart didn't work.
NOTE: 
When I tried installing lubuntu-desktop package on system without DE, autostart also didn't work, there was an error on login "No Session for PID", I thought that it might be the reason.
I installed minimal system without DE and then installed lxde package. And now I see no errors after login and autostart works with .desktop files in /etc/xdg/autostart.

Comment: I actually placed them in `~/.config/autostart`